# In France, can the insurance not apply if my motorcycle has racing parts?

Tags: liability, insurance, france, motorcycle

I have a motorcycle in France that is insured. For clarification, I do ride on road and not on a circuit.

Doing some maintenance, I changed the air filter to a racing one that says to increase air flow (and therefore performances). In the description of the filter is written "Competition use on closed circuit only." and the filter has a different color to clearly indicate it's a racing one. For precision, there is a similar air filter said to be for "performance" that does not contain the "Competition use on closed circuit only." line in the description nor the special color and with smaller indicated air flow.

In case of an accident (responsible or not), can my "all-risks" insurance not apply because of this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Racing parts generally lack EWG certification and thus roadworthiness certificates

[A part needs to have an EWG registration number matching to the type of vehicle to be allowed to be used on a street-legal motorcycle.](https://www.tuningblog.eu/fr/cat%C3%A9gories/wiki-de-r%C3%A9glage/Permis-d%27exploitation-ewg-235351/) If a part has non street-legal parts, its whole registration usually is void. Driving a vehicle without a valid registration is illegal and generally not insured.

Please check the [regulator](https://www.ecologie.gouv.fr/homologation-des-vehicules) or the [general information of insurance companies](https://www.argusdelassurance.com/dossier-ja/securite-des-pieces-de-rechange-et-homologation.39663) about what replacement parts have to comply with. Your insurance agency usually can help you too.

Comment: Thank you for your precise answer. After some research on the official website of the air filter constructor, it turns out they say "Designed especially for very sporty motorcycles, both for road and track use" so I'll take that as an authorized modification.

Comment: @Daxelarne Note that, even if you get an authorized part, you might need to have it noted in your motorcycle papers.

Comment: Thank you, I'll carefully read the instructions of the air filter and will contact my insurance to make sure everything is ok.

Answer (score 1):

The best thing to do is read your policy and ask your insurer.

Some insurance policies do not include modifications from the factory state.

If you have such a policy and do not declare the modification to your insurer, your insurer might be able to void the policy if you make a claim.